# Flipping 3 column grid order in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a 3 column grid that needs to flip column order when the breakpoint is large.

1. At small breakpoint columns should display  col3 col2 col1
2. At medium breakpoint columns should display col2 col1 col3
3. At large breakpoint columns should display  col 1 col2 col3

This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/goyosoyo/q82sc7t4/) behaves correctly for the col-sm and col-md breakpoints.  I've attempted adding push/pull classes to affect the desired large breakpoint behavior (condition 3 above) but am unable to make it work.  I think I'm getting tripped up by the ordering that also occurs at col-md.  I want the small, medium and large ordering behaviors.  How is this accomplished?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12  col-md-3 col-md-push-9 bg-warning">
      column 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12  col-md-5 col-md-pull-3  bg-danger">
      Column 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12  col-md-4 col-md-pull-3  bg-success">Column 1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can check the env and arrange columns with Jacquelyn

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.  Here's the solution in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/goyosoyo/q82sc7t4/12/).

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12  col-md-3 col-md-push-9 bg-warning">
      column 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12  col-md-5 col-md-pull-3 col-lg-push-1 bg-danger">
      Column 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12  col-md-4 col-md-pull-3  col-lg-pull-8 bg-success">Column 1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```